# Why do we pass arguments into a method instead of assigning them as attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am attempting to learn OOP in Python so I wanted to ask why do we pass parameters into the method when calling it, while the object is passed automatically by Python into the method as the first parameter and can be used to automatically identify and call its attributes instead of passing them when calling the method?

Why don't we do this:

```
class Item:
    def calculate_total(self):
        total = self.quantity * self.price
        return total

item = Item()
item.price = 100
item.quantity = 5
item.calculate_total()
```

instead of this:

```
class Item:
    def calculate_total(self, x, y):
        total = x * y
        return total

item = Item()
item.price = 100
item.quantity = 5
item.calculate_total(item.price, item.quantity)
```

Comment: We don't do the latter, we do `item.calculate_total(100, 5)`.

Comment: You could most definitely do #2, your code would run just fine, but a `calculate_total` that never uses the attributes of the class doesn't belong in the class.

Comment: I don't do either of these. I usually design my `__init__` so that I can do `item = Item(100, 5)`.

Comment: Methods can take arguments, but those should be values that _aren't_ available to the class and its objects. For example, if you had a `discount` variable that you got from somewhere else, you could define `calculate_total(self, discount)` to `return self.quantity * self.price * (1 - discount / 100)`

Comment: @mkrieger1 we don't really do that either, we do `Item.calculate_total(100, 5)`, and `@staticmethod`

Comment: @tevemadar Then you don't need a `class` in the first place…

Comment: @deceze yes, sure, but it may happen as grouping/namespace

Comment: @tevemadar Modules provide such namespacing already. A class which is never instantiated should not exist.

Comment: @deceze I wonder if that's not too much of a generalization, considering things like abstract base classes are designed not to be instantiated.

Comment: @matszwecja They're at least instantiated *indirectly* by a subclass in some form or another. But a class with only static methods designed just as a namespace holder which does nothing when instantiated should not exist. As a rule of thumb: if you'd never ever do `isinstance(o, TheClass)`, then the class shouldn't exist. You'd do this with abstract classes, you'd never do that with "`staticmethod` classes".

Comment: @deceze *Modules provide such namespacing already. A class which is never instantiated should not exist.* - I simply meant the "classic" `static` case, when you do have some actual things in `Item` - its name sounds like something meant to be instantiated -, and some `@staticmethod`s naturally accompany them, even though they don't actually need `Item` or `item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is kinda flawed, as none of those should be seen in real-life code.
Attributes should be declared inside the class, preferrably at the moment of object initialisation.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, price, quantity):
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    def calculate_total(self):
        total = self.quantity * self.price
        return total

item = Item(100, 5)
item.calculate_total()
```

This way we don't have a risk of `self.price` and `self.quantity` not being defined when we call `calculate_total`.

But, even with what you provided, why 2nd method would be worse quickly becomes apparent if you try to calculate things multiple times. Let's say you've got 3 slightly different totals (different currency maybe).
Would you rather write

```
item.calculate_total1(item.price, item.quantity)
item.calculate_total2(item.price, item.quantity)
item.calculate_total3(item.price, item.quantity)
```

or

```
item.calculate_total1()
item.calculate_total2()
item.calculate_total2()
```

?

As @Pranav Hosangadi mentions, if there are any parameters that do not have a place in the attributes of a class (e.g. `discount`, which can vary for different sales of the same item), that is where we would pass them to the method:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, price, quantity):
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    def calculate_total(self, discount):
        total = self.quantity * self.price * (1 - discount)
        return total

item = Item(100, 5)
discount = 0.15
print(item.calculate_total(discount))
```